# VB.net project deployment Visual Studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, project

Hi guys i have a question because I have finished building my first application for windows and I used vb.net and the ide is visual studio 2010 what I want to do now is to make a setup file where other users can install my software either by CD or downloading it through the internet... Thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233806(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can goto Build--> Publish and then publish your project with desirable settings as per your requirement. This will make a executable file. You can install anywhere